# Setting VNC on pure 20.04. ubuntu

Tags: vnc

I am trying to set up VNC on newly installed Ubuntu 20.04. I tried most of guides in the internet. My goal is to have VNC reflecting physical display on 5900 port (not 5901). I want to see via VNC what I can see via KVM.

I tried to follow gnome path like here: https://www.how2shout.com/linux/install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-20-04-18-04-lts-to-access-gnome/
I ended up with grey solid screen. I tried tons of xstartup configs and none worked well.

I tried to follow xfce path like here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-20-04
I ended up with broken GUI. When connecting to the system via KVM I just got the grey screen with "Something went wrong" "wallpaper" just like in Win Millennium times.

I would be extremely thankful for some help.

Comment: you can use x11vnc to run vnc server on an existing display

Comment: Thanks! It actually worked with like 5 minute google debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments by Cagri I used x11vnc like here: https://omar2cloud.github.io/rasp/x11vnc/ I had some issues with Display :0 and I simply followed error log to look for .Xauthority -> "ps wwaux | grep auth" and changed -auth. Now everything is working as expected.